# Poisson kernel approaches Dirac delta proof

Tags: harmonic-functions, dirac-delta

I know that the Poisson kernel is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{(1-r^2)}{(1-2r\cos\theta+r^2)}
$$
I'm trying to prove this converges to Dirac delta $\delta(\theta)$ when $r \rightarrow 1^-$ and have no IDEA, can you please help ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The denominator should be $1-2r \cos \theta +r^2$... Besides what is the meaning of $r \to r^{-}1$ ?

Comment: Yeah! You are right, sorry for that! I mean limit r approaches 1 from the negative.

Comment: Kind of nervous first time uploading a problem, sorry! I've corrected the question.

Comment: Why $\sin^2 \theta$ instead of $1$ ?

Comment: Sorry another typo...corrected

Comment: Do you know that the denominator can be written under the complex form $|1-re^{i \theta}|^2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the following practical criterion allowing to say that a sequence $f_n(x)$ that converges to $\delta$ ?

It is enough (sufficient condition, thanks to David C. Ullrich who has pointed this) for this sequence to verify three items:

- For any fixed $x \ne 0$: $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=0$.
- (if $x = 0$) $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(0)=\infty$.
- For all $n$: $ \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx=1 \ $(normalization).

Now take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1022983 ...

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But isn't it a more concrete way to prove that $<f_n(x), \phi(x)>=\phi(0)$? To prove it in a generalized function(distribution) way.

Comment: It depends on the degree of rigor your instructor desires... This kind of proof is very usual, with no pitfall (that one can have occasionaly with $\delta$ distributions). One has here a way to avoid the rather heavy burden of using test functions $\phi$...

Comment: Yeah, sure, that is making life much easier. Thanks a lot for advice and also... for the typos... Hope I'll get smarter enough to ask a smarter question next time. Still, best thanks!

Comment: "must verify"? No. Those conditions are _sufficient_ but certainly not necessary.

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich You are right. I will modify my text.

Comment: See Theorem 1.20 p. 27 of [this document](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/masdoc/people/masdoc_alumni/davidmccormick/ara-v0.1.pdf).