# Evaluate $\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r \cos(\theta) +r^2}d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $0 < r < 1$. Compute
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1 - r^2}{1 - 2r \cos(\theta) +r^2}d\theta$$
The hint is rewrite this integral as a complex line, but I still don't know how to to it

Comment: Maybe $\cos t = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$ can help.

Comment: hint  :$$z=\frac{(-r-cos\theta)+i sin \theta}{(r-cos\theta) +isin \theta} \\Re(z)=?\\Re(z)=Re\frac{(-r-cos\theta)+i sin \theta}{(r-cos\theta) +isin \theta}*\frac{(r-cos\theta)-i sin \theta}{(r-cos\theta) -isin \theta}=\\\frac{((-r-cos\theta)(r-cos\theta)-i^2sin^2 \theta}{((r-cos\theta)^2-i^2sin^2 \theta}=\frac{-r^2+cos^2 \theta +sin^2 \theta}{r^2-2rcos \theta +cos^2 \theta +sin^2 \theta}=\frac{-r^2+1}{r^2+1-2rcos \theta}$$

Comment: @daryakhosrotash Is this a hint?

Comment: This question was discussed many times on this site, please have a close look.

Comment: @tired: I just found [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1005102), which is closely related and my answer there answers this question using contour integration rather than the mean value property.

Comment: @Math-fun: one could use the indefinite integral, but since this is a definite integral, there are often other (possibly simpler) methods of integration.

Comment: @robjohn this is true, I agree. I was not sure if this is an exact duplicate, though in the link I thought relevant, there is a solution to this question with the same bounds. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Mean Value Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}
\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})}
\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u\left(re^{i\theta}\right)\mathrm{d}\theta\\[6pt]
&=u(0)\\[12pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
 where $u(z)=\frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2}=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$ is a [Harmonic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The denominator can be expressed as $(1-e^{i\theta}r)(1-e^{-i\theta}r)$.